# I can upload images to specific directory but can't view them in template (Page not found (404))

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-media

I am trying to add upload image to admin form in my Django project I found on [GitHub](https://github.com/mdn/django-locallibrary-tutorial). I can upload image to folder `my_app(catalog)/media/images/image.png` but when I try to call it in the template I can only see that image icon that appears when there is no picture.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'catalog/media')
```

model.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null = True, upload_to='images')
```

book_detail.html

```
img src="{{ book.image.url}}" width="250"
```

views.py

```
class BookDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Book
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('book/create/', views.BookCreate.as_view(), name='book_create'),
    path('books/', views.BookListView.as_view(), name='books'),
    path('book/<int:pk>', views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='book-detail'),

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is how it looks like (I print {{ book.image }} next to the picture (`images/screenshot_4.png`):

[image]

This is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: Please replace screenshots of text with text.

Comment: try this => {{ book.image.url }}

Answer (score 0):

You may have dropped a ']' at the end of your urlpatterns or maybe I am mistaken

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out after spending way to much time on it.
img src="{{ book.image.url}}" width="250" line in template should look like 
img src="../media/{{ book.image.url}}" width="250".

Hope this helps someone with the same problem.